# jQuery toggle switch checkbox - changing "checked" attribute delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, togglebutton

I created a toggle switch checkbox and aplied the logic below:

1] If user clicks on toggle switch `class="os_section-slider"` the script will check if the `input` containing element's name is checked.

1-A] If the element is checked then change it to UNchecked and add that element into array named `os_tagsToRemove`

1-B] If the element is UNchecked then change it to checked and add that element into array named `os_tagsToAdd`

**HTML**

```
<span class="os_section-name">first</span>
<input type="checkbox" class="os_section-check" id="first" checked="checked">
<label class="os_section-slider" for="first"></label>

<div class="line-space-between"></div>

<span class="os_section-name">second</span>
<input type="checkbox" class="os_section-check" id="second">
<label class="os_section-slider" for="second"></label>
```

**JS**

```
$(".os_section-slider").click(function() {
    if($(this).prev().is(":checked")) {   //if checked
        $(this).prev().attr("checked", false);
        var os_tagName = $(this).prev().attr("id").toString();
        os_tagsToRemove.push(os_tagName);
        os_tagsToAdd.splice($.inArray(os_tagName, os_tagsToAdd),1);
    } else {    //if unchecked
        $(this).prev().attr("checked", true);
        var os_tagName = $(this).prev().attr("id").toString();
        os_tagsToAdd.push(os_tagName);
        os_tagsToRemove.splice($.inArray(os_tagName, os_tagsToRemove),1);
    }
});
```

My problem is, when my page reloads and my toggle switch appears in a modal box and I try to click on the switcher button I have to click 2 times until the checked attribute is added/removed.

The first click always only pushes the value into the array or removes it from the array but doesn't apply `$(this).prev().attr("checked", true);` nor `$(this).prev().attr("checked", false);`.

But after the second click on each switcher button, everything from that moment works fine.

Comment: I don't get how you click on your empty labels... And I don't get why you attach the click events on the labels instead of the checkboxes. Explain that.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I need my script to change the checked attribute for each element in the way that the source code of the page will be changed too. When You have a default checkbox then if You check/uncheck  an element's input it will not hard code `checked="checked"` into the source code of the page.

Comment: Haa... ok that's about a defaulted checked... Hold on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to load your add/remove arrays:

```
// Onload remove array fill
$("[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
  if( $(this).is(":checked") ){
    os_tagsToRemove.push($(this).attr("id"));
  }else{
    os_tagsToAdd.push($(this).attr("id"));
  }
});
```

Then, your logic was all reversed.

First, when you click on the label, which is defined as `for="anID"`, the checked state of the coresponding checkbox already changes. You do not have to script that.

Then, when you look if it is checked, you have to know that this verification is made AFTER the checkbox state has changed. So I reversed your `if` conditions.

```js
var os_tagsToAdd = [];
var os_tagsToRemove = [];

$(".os_section-slider").click(function() {
  console.clear();

  var os_tagName = $(this).prev().attr("id");

  //if checked AFTER the click
  if($(this).prev().is(":checked")) {
    if($.inArray(os_tagName, os_tagsToAdd) == -1){
      os_tagsToAdd.push(os_tagName);
    }
    os_tagsToRemove.splice($.inArray(os_tagName, os_tagsToRemove),1);

    //if unchecked AFTER the click
  } else {
    if($.inArray(os_tagName, os_tagsToRemove) == -1){
      os_tagsToRemove.push(os_tagName);
    }
    os_tagsToAdd.splice($.inArray(os_tagName, os_tagsToAdd),1);
  }

  console.log( os_tagsToAdd );
  console.log( os_tagsToRemove );
});

// Onload remove array fill
$("[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
  if( $(this).is(":checked") ){
    os_tagsToRemove.push($(this).attr("id"));
  }else{
    os_tagsToAdd.push($(this).attr("id"));
  }
});

console.log( os_tagsToAdd );
console.log( os_tagsToRemove );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="os_section-name">first</span>
<input type="checkbox" class="os_section-check" id="first" checked="checked">
<label class="os_section-slider" for="first">Label</label>

<div class="line-space-between"></div>

<span class="os_section-name">second</span>
<input type="checkbox" class="os_section-check" id="second">
<label class="os_section-slider" for="second">Label</label>
```

Comment: Your script is fixed. Feel free to ask questions if it ain't clear!

Comment: Notice that a direct click on the checkboxes mess that all... But I suppose you use some nice CSS to hide it anyway. ;)